# Custom Function call at controller not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Grettings.

This is the first time I try to do my own function, and seems that something is wrong at the function calling because I only see a blank screen.

I want to make a search of a user, all that data will be displayed at the rigth when clicking the "Buscar" button. The data to look for is at the input control up the button (The image is atteched down).

This are my routes

```
    Route::resource('escuelausuarios','EscuelaUsuariosController');
    Route::get('registroaccesos/search/{$patron}', 'RegistroAccesosController@search')->name('registroaccesos.search');     
    Route::get('registroaccesos/otra/', 'RegistroAccesosController@otra')->name('registroaccesos.otra');        
    Route::resource('registroaccesos','RegistroAccesosController');
```

I send you the index function where the call is defined, with javascript. I guess there's something wrong with action

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
   <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Grupos</a>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<nav class="col-sm-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
<div class="sidebar-sticky">
<h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
   <span>Acciones</span>
   <a class="d-flex align-items-center text-muted" href="#">
   <span data-feather="plus-circle"></span>
   </a>
</h6>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="strSearch" class="col-form-label">Patrón de búsqueda</label>
   <select name="strSearch" class="form-control">
      <option value="1"  selected> Código del usuario</option>
      <option value="2"  > Nombre del usuario</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <input  placeholder="Patrón de búsqueda"
      id="strPatron"
      required
      name="strPatron"
      spellcheck="false" 
      class="form-control"
      />
</div>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
   onclick="
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('search-form').submit();
   "
   >Buscar</button>
<form id="search-form" action="{{ route('registroaccesos.otra'  ) }}"
   method="POST" style="display: none;">
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

This is the function (otra) is being called when clicking "Buscar" Button.

```
public function search($patron="")
{
    //
    $patron = 'Hola';
    dd($patron);
    return;
}

public function otra()
{
    //

    dd(1);
    return;
}
```

[image]

Seems the call is taking place when clicking "Buscar" button but as I told you, I only see a blank screen.

[image]

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what action has taken place to get to the blank screen, which route are you accessing and what is the controller code for that action? You also have multiple routes that end with 2 semicolons, which won't help.

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
   onclick="
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('search-form').submit();
   "
   >Buscar</button>` What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: I updated my post to show what you told me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a route of GET request which is:

```
Route::get('registroaccesos/otra/', 'RegistroAccesosController@otra')->name('registroaccesos.otra');
```

You are submitting POST request through the form that's why it is unable to handle that request.

Try changing your GET request to POST as follows:

```
Route::post('registroaccesos/otra/', 'RegistroAccesosController@otra')->name('registroaccesos.otra');
```

Comment: Sounds very logic and I agree with that, must be something like it, but it didn't works. Could you give me an advise of what could I do to solve my need? I want to look for a user, but, as you can see I'm not using a different form, that's why I used javascript for calling the route, I want to show the results at right, the same page. So, I actually don't know if I have to use get or post, as a matter of fact I should send the pattern I want to find, that's why there is a function called search, with a parameter, that I have not used yet.

Comment: You had reason, the problem was that, but I changet the method at index, had post and changed to get, so, now the function is being called, but the call had a parameter called token, when the definition of the route don't, something like      http://localhost:81/gymmgr/public/registroaccesos/otra?_token=10578bLb35V9H9K0D5HKMuW5AwPfEOd1LRaFoSt9.  What could it mean??